# One URL for cross platform, multi territory mobile app. Is it possible?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, windows-phone, app-store

I have an app that I'm hoping will be published on IOS, android and windows phone stores.
The app is targeted at visitors to Australia, will be multilingual and published in multiple territories.

I want to have just one URL for the app.

The device detection part I understand.

My question is, I get a visitor whose App Store territory is set to China perhaps, does the app have the same store URL as for the visitor whose territory is Korea or Japan or wherever? And Is it the same scenario across the three platforms?

For clarification, it's just one app, the language selection is on the splash screen.

Ideally I'd like it to work like this:
URL> device detection> URL for IOS all territories, URL for android all territories, URL for WP all territories.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe the URL is set by language and not territory, and the URL will be different for each language.
For example, here's the US URL for one of my apps:

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/uta-rider/id668469368?ls=1&mt=8

Notice the /us/ portion. Here's the same app with /es/ :

https://itunes.apple.com/es/app/uta-rider/id668469368?ls=1&mt=8

Even though my description and screenshots have only been made in English, the URL is different for each language as the iTunes page is loaded in its correct local language.

Comment: That's interesting because regardless of which of the two links I use I end up with the English version, presumably on the Australian App Store. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone you can leave the language out from the url (it is even recommended to not use it). Windows phone store automatically detects user language/locale and displays the app details using detected language.

Your url is something like: http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid={AppID}